# Using Hebrew in django user name

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I've notice django admin UI does not allow use name with characters that are not English.
I need to use Hebrew characters for user names.

Someone try it?

Thank you,
Ido.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll want to set the proper collation for your sitewide databases, or, at least the one that holds the user information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/databases/#collation-settings

Comment: the collaction is not the issue because I can enter Hebrew text in my own model tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django auth module admin limits username to be matching `r'^[\w.@+-]+$'`. You need to replace the default forms inside ModelAdmin instance: UserAdmin.form and UserAdmin.add_form, like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import User, UserAdmin as UserAdmin_

admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin_):
    add_form = ... # customized form based on auth.forms.UserCreationForm
    form = ... # customized form based on auth.forms.UserChangeForm

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```